# Kendo-UI Cascading ComboBox client filtering

Tags: jquery, combobox, kendo-ui, cascadingdropdown, cascade-filtering

I'm using cascading comboboxes to narrow down a choice for, say cities. My scenario differs slightly from the examples provided on http://kendoui.com since I can't make asynchronous server calls after the page is loaded.

Here's an example of my code:

---

HTML

```
<p>
    <label for="Country">Country:</label>
    <input id="country"/>
</p>
<p>
    <label for="City">City:</label>
    <input id="city" disabled="disabled" />
</p>
```

---

Script (adding the datasource inline for simplicity)

```
$("#country").kendoComboBox({
    placeholder: "Select a country...",
    dataTextField: "CountryName",
    dataValueField: "CountryID",
    dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
            data: [
            {
                    CountryID: "1",
                    CountryName: "Sweden"
            },
            {
                    CountryID: "2",
                    CountryName: "Spain"
            }]
    }),
});

$("#city").kendoComboBox({
    autoBind: false,
    cascadeFrom: "country",
    placeholder: "Select city...",
    dataTextField: "CityName",
    dataValueField: "CountryID",
    dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
            data: [
            {
                    CountryID: "1",
                    CityID: "1",
                    CityName: "Stockholm"
            },
            {
                    CountryID: "1",
                    CityID: "2",
                    CityName: "Gothenburg"
            },
            {
                    CountryID: "1",
                    CityID: "3",
                    CityName: "Malmo"
            },
            {
                    CountryID: "2",
                    CityID: "4",
                    CityName: "Madrid"
            }]
    }),
})
```

This works indeed, picking 'Sweden' in the first list will generate Stockholm, Gothenburg and Malmo in the second box. But requires that one use the same dataValueField for both child and parent, hence when I've selected a city, the selected value will be CountryID instead of CityID which I want.

The right way to go about it (I guess) should be to use dataValueField: CityID in #city and do a client side select/filtering similar to: (Note, pseudo code)

```
SELECT CityID, CityName WHERE CountryID EQUALS country.dataValue
```

That would fetch the right dataValue (CityID) from the city combobox when a city is selected.

Does anyone know how to solve this? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not understanding your question: Why do you say that you cannot define `dataValueField: "CityID",` in `#city`?

Comment: If I'd set the dataValueField to CityID in #city the cascading would cease to work.
The child combobox seems to match its dataValueField with the parents selected value if -and only if -they both have the same variable name.

Comment: Sure? Check it here http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/cc3d4/ What is failing (click on `Show` for displaying current values)

Comment: Man. You are asbolutely right! Thought I had tried that hundreds of times.
That really helped me out of a tricky situation. Hats off to you! :)

Comment: So... problem solved? :-)